# Executor in java with Runnable Object

Tags: java, runnable, executors

I was trying to learn the Executors and is having doubts.

Assuming that I has 2 Runnable objects `Socket1Write` and `Socket2Write` which have a run method. Run methods have an infinite loop which will write data to a TCP Socket. The socket is a common socket for both classes. But when I call both threads using `Executor` only one is getting called and processed, i.e. the first `Runnable` is getting picked up always.

Below are the ways I tried.

```
ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Runnable runner1 = new Socket1Write(consumer, socks);
Runnable runner2 = new Socket1Write1(consumer, socks);
executor.execute(runner1);
executor.execute(runner2);

ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
ExecutorService executor1=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Runnable runner1 = new Socket1Write(consumer, socks);
Runnable runner2 = new Socket1Write1(consumer, socks);
executor.execute(runner1);
executor1.execute(runner2);

ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Future<Object>> future=new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

List<Callable<Object>> callList = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
callList.add(new Socket1Write(consumer, socks));
callList.add(new Socket2Write(consumer, socks));
future = pool.invokeAll(callList);
```

As from my understanding the executor should pick up each thread that need to be executed. Am I missing any thing else here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which executor are you talking about? Why do you have 3 of them?

Comment: @ JB Nizet .I tried with java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService for the same.Shown are the 3 different ways by which i tried .

Comment: The answer would depend on which one you chose. Please focus on one way of doing. And post the code of the task.